# Referencing dynamically created tablerows in Modal Popup Extender Panel

Tags: dynamically-generated, tablerow, modalpopupextender

I have created a Modal Popup Extender with a panel containing a html table.  I populate the html table by dynamically adding table rows within the panel. The table rows are successfully added to the html table.  After modifying the table in the browser, I need to update a datatable from the html table by pressing a "Save" button in the panel.  I can find the table control using findcontrol, but none of the dynamically added table rows can be referenced.  Row count comes back 0.  Any suggestions will be helpful.  Code below

Client Side

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="LaborHourPopupExt" runat="server" PopupControlID="LaborHourPanel" TargetControlID="lnkFake"
            CancelControlID="CancelHourLaborEntry" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
        </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="LaborHourPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalTimeCardPopup" Style="display: none">
            <div class="header">
                Manage Hourly Labor
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <asp:Table ID="HourLaborTable" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <asp:TableRow runat="server"></asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <asp:Button ID="SaveHourLaborEntry" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="yes" OnClick="UpdateTaskTable" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelHourLaborEntry" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="yes" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

protected void UpdateTaskTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Table TaskTableCopy = (Table)FindControl("HourLaborTable");
        Response.Write(TaskTableCopy.Rows.Count);
        for (int i = 1; i < TaskTableCopy.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[2] != null & TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[3] != null & TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[4] != null & TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[5] != null)
            {
                DataRow[] CurrentTaskRow = CurrentProject.TaskTable.Select("[dtp:Id]=" + TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[0]);
                DataRow[] CurrentTechnicianRow = CurrentProject.TechnicianTable.Select("[dtp:Name] = " + CurrentTaskRow[0]["ResourceName"]);
                if (CurrentTaskRow[0] != null)
                {
                    CurrentTaskRow[0]["dtp:StartDate"] = TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[3] + "T" +TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[4];
                    CurrentTaskRow[0]["dtp:EndDate"] = TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[3] + "T" + TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[5];
                    CurrentTaskRow[0]["dtp:ResourceName"] = TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[2];
                    CurrentTaskRow[0]["dtp:ResourceID"] = CurrentTechnicianRow[0]["dtp:Id"];
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow NewTaskRow = CurrentProject.TechnicianTable.NewRow();
                    NewTaskRow["dtp:Id"] = TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                    NewTaskRow["dtp:Name"] = TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[1];
                    NewTaskRow["dtp:StartDate"] = TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[3];
                    NewTaskRow["dtp:StartDate"] = TaskTableCopy.Rows[i].Cells[4];
                    NewTaskRow["dtp:ResourceID"] = CurrentTechnicianRow[0]["dtp:Id"];
                    CurrentProject.TaskTable.Rows.Add(NewTaskRow);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```